# Android - What is the difference between compileSDKVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:22" & "22"?

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-manifest

Inside the Gradle.build file I see some projects using

**compileSdkVersion="Google Inc.:Google APIs:22"**

and some are just using the number

**compileSdkVersion="22"**

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one builds against an `android.jar` that contains the long-since-discontinued Maps V1. The second one does not.

Note that the current version of Google Maps for Android, known as Maps V2, is part of the Play Services SDK and therefore does not need a special `compileSdkVersion`.

IMHO, the first one is a code smell, with the sole exception being if the code actually does use Maps V1.

Comment: Gradle would not let me build my MapsV1 app until I changed compileSdkVersion=14 to compileSdkVersion="Google Inc.:Google APIs:14". Thank you for this post.